# WildFly opening excessive amounts of ports

Tags: java, windows, performance, port, wildfly

We're running WildFly 11 (Final), after reports of the system being slow, which were approximately every second day, we found that a lot of ports (sample list below) are being opened.

Does anyone have a theory as to why so many ports are opened?
Also could the excessive amounts of ports opened cause the system to be slow?

```
Proto Local Address    Foreign Address  State        PID
TCP   127.0.0.1:49390  127.0.0.1:49387  ESTABLISHED  7796 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49402  127.0.0.1:49403  ESTABLISHED  7796 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49403  127.0.0.1:49402  ESTABLISHED  7796 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49404  127.0.0.1:49405  ESTABLISHED  7796 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49405  127.0.0.1:49404  ESTABLISHED  7796 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49406  127.0.0.1:49407  ESTABLISHED  7796 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49407  127.0.0.1:49406  ESTABLISHED  7796 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49697  127.0.0.1:49698  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49698  127.0.0.1:49697  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49699  127.0.0.1:49700  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49700  127.0.0.1:49699  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49701  127.0.0.1:49702  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49702  127.0.0.1:49701  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49704  127.0.0.1:49705  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49705  127.0.0.1:49704  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49706  127.0.0.1:49707  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49707  127.0.0.1:49706  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49708  127.0.0.1:49709  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49709  127.0.0.1:49708  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49710  127.0.0.1:49711  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49711  127.0.0.1:49710  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49712  127.0.0.1:49713  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49713  127.0.0.1:49712  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49714  127.0.0.1:49715  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49715  127.0.0.1:49714  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49716  127.0.0.1:49717  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49717  127.0.0.1:49716  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49718  127.0.0.1:49719  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49719  127.0.0.1:49718  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49720  127.0.0.1:49721  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49721  127.0.0.1:49720  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49722  127.0.0.1:49723  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49723  127.0.0.1:49722  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49724  127.0.0.1:49725  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49725  127.0.0.1:49724  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49726  127.0.0.1:49727  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49727  127.0.0.1:49726  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49728  127.0.0.1:49729  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49729  127.0.0.1:49728  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49730  127.0.0.1:49731  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49731  127.0.0.1:49730  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49732  127.0.0.1:49733  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49733  127.0.0.1:49732  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49734  127.0.0.1:49735  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49735  127.0.0.1:49734  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49736  127.0.0.1:49737  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49737  127.0.0.1:49736  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49738  127.0.0.1:49739  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49739  127.0.0.1:49738  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49740  127.0.0.1:49741  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49741  127.0.0.1:49740  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49742  127.0.0.1:49743  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49743  127.0.0.1:49742  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49744  127.0.0.1:49745  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49745  127.0.0.1:49744  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49746  127.0.0.1:49747  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49747  127.0.0.1:49746  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49748  127.0.0.1:49749  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49749  127.0.0.1:49748  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49750  127.0.0.1:49751  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49751  127.0.0.1:49750  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49752  127.0.0.1:49753  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49753  127.0.0.1:49752  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49754  127.0.0.1:49755  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49755  127.0.0.1:49754  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49756  127.0.0.1:49757  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49757  127.0.0.1:49756  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49758  127.0.0.1:49759  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49759  127.0.0.1:49758  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49760  127.0.0.1:49761  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49761  127.0.0.1:49760  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49762  127.0.0.1:49763  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49763  127.0.0.1:49762  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49764  127.0.0.1:49765  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49765  127.0.0.1:49764  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49766  127.0.0.1:49767  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49767  127.0.0.1:49766  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49768  127.0.0.1:49769  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49769  127.0.0.1:49768  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49770  127.0.0.1:49771  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49771  127.0.0.1:49770  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49776  127.0.0.1:49777  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49777  127.0.0.1:49776  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49778  127.0.0.1:49779  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49779  127.0.0.1:49778  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49780  127.0.0.1:49781  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49781  127.0.0.1:49780  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49782  127.0.0.1:49783  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49783  127.0.0.1:49782  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49784  127.0.0.1:49785  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49785  127.0.0.1:49784  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49786  127.0.0.1:49787  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49787  127.0.0.1:49786  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49788  127.0.0.1:49789  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49789  127.0.0.1:49788  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49790  127.0.0.1:49791  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49791  127.0.0.1:49790  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49792  127.0.0.1:49793  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49793  127.0.0.1:49792  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49794  127.0.0.1:49795  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49795  127.0.0.1:49794  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49796  127.0.0.1:49797  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49797  127.0.0.1:49796  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49798  127.0.0.1:49799  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49799  127.0.0.1:49798  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49800  127.0.0.1:49801  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49801  127.0.0.1:49800  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49802  127.0.0.1:49803  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49803  127.0.0.1:49802  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49804  127.0.0.1:49805  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49805  127.0.0.1:49804  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49806  127.0.0.1:49807  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49807  127.0.0.1:49806  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49808  127.0.0.1:49809  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49809  127.0.0.1:49808  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49810  127.0.0.1:49811  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49811  127.0.0.1:49810  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49812  127.0.0.1:49813  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49813  127.0.0.1:49812  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49814  127.0.0.1:49815  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49815  127.0.0.1:49814  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49816  127.0.0.1:49817  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49817  127.0.0.1:49816  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49818  127.0.0.1:49819  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49819  127.0.0.1:49818  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49820  127.0.0.1:49821  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49821  127.0.0.1:49820  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49822  127.0.0.1:49823  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49823  127.0.0.1:49822  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49824  127.0.0.1:49825  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49825  127.0.0.1:49824  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49826  127.0.0.1:49827  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49827  127.0.0.1:49826  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49828  127.0.0.1:49829  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49829  127.0.0.1:49828  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49830  127.0.0.1:49831  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49831  127.0.0.1:49830  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49832  127.0.0.1:49833  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49833  127.0.0.1:49832  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49834  127.0.0.1:49835  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49835  127.0.0.1:49834  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49836  127.0.0.1:49837  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49837  127.0.0.1:49836  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49838  127.0.0.1:49839  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49839  127.0.0.1:49838  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49840  127.0.0.1:49841  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49841  127.0.0.1:49840  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49842  127.0.0.1:49843  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49843  127.0.0.1:49842  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49844  127.0.0.1:49845  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49845  127.0.0.1:49844  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49846  127.0.0.1:49847  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49847  127.0.0.1:49846  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49848  127.0.0.1:49849  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49849  127.0.0.1:49848  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49850  127.0.0.1:49851  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49851  127.0.0.1:49850  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49852  127.0.0.1:49853  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49853  127.0.0.1:49852  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49854  127.0.0.1:49855  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49855  127.0.0.1:49854  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49856  127.0.0.1:49857  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49857  127.0.0.1:49856  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49858  127.0.0.1:49859  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49859  127.0.0.1:49858  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49860  127.0.0.1:49861  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49861  127.0.0.1:49860  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49862  127.0.0.1:49863  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49863  127.0.0.1:49862  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49864  127.0.0.1:49865  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49865  127.0.0.1:49864  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49866  127.0.0.1:49867  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49867  127.0.0.1:49866  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49868  127.0.0.1:49869  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49869  127.0.0.1:49868  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49870  127.0.0.1:49871  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49871  127.0.0.1:49870  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49872  127.0.0.1:49873  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49873  127.0.0.1:49872  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49874  127.0.0.1:49875  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49875  127.0.0.1:49874  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49876  127.0.0.1:49877  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49877  127.0.0.1:49876  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49878  127.0.0.1:49879  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49879  127.0.0.1:49878  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49880  127.0.0.1:49881  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49881  127.0.0.1:49880  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49882  127.0.0.1:49883  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49883  127.0.0.1:49882  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49884  127.0.0.1:49885  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49885  127.0.0.1:49884  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49886  127.0.0.1:49887  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49887  127.0.0.1:49886  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49888  127.0.0.1:49889  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49889  127.0.0.1:49888  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49890  127.0.0.1:49891  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49891  127.0.0.1:49890  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49892  127.0.0.1:49893  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49893  127.0.0.1:49892  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49894  127.0.0.1:49895  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49895  127.0.0.1:49894  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49896  127.0.0.1:49897  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49897  127.0.0.1:49896  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49898  127.0.0.1:49899  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49899  127.0.0.1:49898  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49900  127.0.0.1:49901  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49901  127.0.0.1:49900  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49902  127.0.0.1:49903  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49903  127.0.0.1:49902  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49904  127.0.0.1:49905  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49905  127.0.0.1:49904  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49906  127.0.0.1:49907  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49907  127.0.0.1:49906  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49908  127.0.0.1:49909  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49909  127.0.0.1:49908  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49910  127.0.0.1:49911  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49911  127.0.0.1:49910  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49912  127.0.0.1:49913  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49913  127.0.0.1:49912  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49914  127.0.0.1:49915  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49915  127.0.0.1:49914  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49916  127.0.0.1:49917  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49917  127.0.0.1:49916  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49918  127.0.0.1:49919  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49919  127.0.0.1:49918  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49920  127.0.0.1:49921  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49921  127.0.0.1:49920  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49922  127.0.0.1:49923  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49923  127.0.0.1:49922  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49924  127.0.0.1:49925  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49925  127.0.0.1:49924  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49926  127.0.0.1:49927  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49927  127.0.0.1:49926  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49928  127.0.0.1:49929  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49929  127.0.0.1:49928  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49930  127.0.0.1:49931  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49931  127.0.0.1:49930  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49932  127.0.0.1:49933  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49933  127.0.0.1:49932  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49934  127.0.0.1:49935  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49935  127.0.0.1:49934  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49936  127.0.0.1:49937  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49937  127.0.0.1:49936  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49938  127.0.0.1:49939  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49939  127.0.0.1:49938  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49940  127.0.0.1:49941  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49941  127.0.0.1:49940  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49942  127.0.0.1:49943  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49943  127.0.0.1:49942  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49944  127.0.0.1:49945  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49945  127.0.0.1:49944  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49946  127.0.0.1:49947  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49947  127.0.0.1:49946  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49948  127.0.0.1:49949  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49949  127.0.0.1:49948  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49950  127.0.0.1:49951  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49951  127.0.0.1:49950  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49952  127.0.0.1:49953  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49953  127.0.0.1:49952  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49954  127.0.0.1:49955  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49955  127.0.0.1:49954  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49956  127.0.0.1:49957  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49957  127.0.0.1:49956  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49958  127.0.0.1:49959  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49959  127.0.0.1:49958  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49960  127.0.0.1:49961  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49961  127.0.0.1:49960  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49962  127.0.0.1:49963  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49963  127.0.0.1:49962  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49964  127.0.0.1:49965  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49965  127.0.0.1:49964  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49966  127.0.0.1:49967  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49967  127.0.0.1:49966  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49982  127.0.0.1:49983  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49983  127.0.0.1:49982  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49984  127.0.0.1:49985  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49985  127.0.0.1:49984  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49986  127.0.0.1:49987  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49987  127.0.0.1:49986  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49988  127.0.0.1:49989  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49989  127.0.0.1:49988  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49990  127.0.0.1:49991  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49991  127.0.0.1:49990  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49992  127.0.0.1:49993  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49993  127.0.0.1:49992  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49994  127.0.0.1:49995  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49995  127.0.0.1:49994  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49996  127.0.0.1:49997  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49997  127.0.0.1:49996  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49998  127.0.0.1:49999  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:49999  127.0.0.1:49998  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50000  127.0.0.1:50001  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50001  127.0.0.1:50000  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50002  127.0.0.1:50003  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50003  127.0.0.1:50002  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50004  127.0.0.1:50005  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50005  127.0.0.1:50004  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50006  127.0.0.1:50007  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50007  127.0.0.1:50006  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50008  127.0.0.1:50009  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50009  127.0.0.1:50008  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50010  127.0.0.1:50011  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50011  127.0.0.1:50010  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50012  127.0.0.1:50013  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50013  127.0.0.1:50012  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50022  127.0.0.1:50023  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50023  127.0.0.1:50022  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50024  127.0.0.1:50025  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50025  127.0.0.1:50024  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50027  127.0.0.1:50028  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50028  127.0.0.1:50027  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50030  127.0.0.1:50031  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50031  127.0.0.1:50030  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50032  127.0.0.1:50033  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50033  127.0.0.1:50032  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50034  127.0.0.1:50035  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50035  127.0.0.1:50034  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50036  127.0.0.1:50037  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50037  127.0.0.1:50036  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50038  127.0.0.1:50039  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50039  127.0.0.1:50038  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50040  127.0.0.1:50041  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50041  127.0.0.1:50040  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50042  127.0.0.1:50043  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50043  127.0.0.1:50042  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50054  127.0.0.1:50055  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50055  127.0.0.1:50054  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50056  127.0.0.1:50057  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50057  127.0.0.1:50056  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50059  127.0.0.1:50060  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50060  127.0.0.1:50059  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50061  127.0.0.1:50062  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50062  127.0.0.1:50061  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50063  127.0.0.1:50064  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50064  127.0.0.1:50063  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50067  127.0.0.1:50068  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50068  127.0.0.1:50067  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50069  127.0.0.1:50070  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50070  127.0.0.1:50069  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50072  127.0.0.1:50073  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50073  127.0.0.1:50072  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50074  127.0.0.1:50075  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50075  127.0.0.1:50074  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50076  127.0.0.1:50077  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50077  127.0.0.1:50076  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50078  127.0.0.1:50079  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50079  127.0.0.1:50078  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50080  127.0.0.1:50081  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50081  127.0.0.1:50080  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50082  127.0.0.1:50083  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50083  127.0.0.1:50082  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50084  127.0.0.1:50085  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50085  127.0.0.1:50084  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50086  127.0.0.1:50087  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50087  127.0.0.1:50086  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50088  127.0.0.1:50089  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50089  127.0.0.1:50088  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50091  127.0.0.1:50092  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50092  127.0.0.1:50091  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50093  127.0.0.1:50094  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50094  127.0.0.1:50093  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50095  127.0.0.1:50096  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50096  127.0.0.1:50095  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50097  127.0.0.1:50098  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50098  127.0.0.1:50097  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50099  127.0.0.1:50100  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50100  127.0.0.1:50099  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50101  127.0.0.1:50102  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50102  127.0.0.1:50101  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50103  127.0.0.1:50104  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50104  127.0.0.1:50103  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50105  127.0.0.1:50106  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50106  127.0.0.1:50105  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50107  127.0.0.1:50108  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50108  127.0.0.1:50107  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50109  127.0.0.1:50110  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50110  127.0.0.1:50109  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50111  127.0.0.1:50112  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50112  127.0.0.1:50111  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50114  127.0.0.1:50115  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50115  127.0.0.1:50114  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50116  127.0.0.1:50117  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50117  127.0.0.1:50116  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50118  127.0.0.1:50119  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50119  127.0.0.1:50118  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50120  127.0.0.1:50121  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50121  127.0.0.1:50120  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50122  127.0.0.1:50123  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
TCP   127.0.0.1:50123  127.0.0.1:50122  ESTABLISHED  9652 [java.exe]
```

Comment: How are you initializing your server?

Comment: I might just add that when starting the server there are a lot less ports open.
The server has 2 nodes and is started using the domain.bat. Would you like the configuration for the domain.xml?

Comment: Man, only with this information I think it's impossible try to help you.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the information you need?

Comment: What are the ports you configured to use?

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help, we've located where we believe the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be related to our implementation of our web services that run every minute. This seems to spawn a new instance with a new port every time.